# How do i detect if an image has a gradient or not?

Tags: image-processing, histogram, gradient

I have coloured images, some may be just clipart, some may be artwork, both could be with or without gradients.

Before i run a colour counting algorithm on them, i want to detect if the image has only solid block colours, or gradients in it.(Technically all compressed images will have small gradients in the form of anti aliasing, but i want to detect the gradients that were there in the original image)

I'm thinking of an approach in which i could plot a historam(of rgb or hsl values, or even grayscale) and if it has peaks that are smooth and not steep, then that indicates that the image may have an area with a gradual colour shift, with all colours of one hue appearing more or less equally(like the image of a sky would have gradual changes from blue to lighter blue to white).
Does this sound right?
Any other approaches for doing this?
Thank you.

Comment: I might be missing something, but shouldn't you just compute the image gradient?

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this. i checked that opencv has a function called gradient, which when i ran on an image, gave results similar to what an edge detector would, ie, sharp changes in colour. What i need is to get a 0/1-yes or no result on the input image telling me if it has a gradient(in the form of shading in colours) or not. Is there a way to do that with that function? thanks.

Comment: for example, for the first image i should be able to extract a negative result, and for the second, a positive one.
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSF4SfnR6OyR6NqsbtQQ-QuKnE3Ga3PbN1KHXf2yPZqQ_blY1z33A

https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTe3fJ2uPs-W8FRM5j6R0eSXbvum03Xk_ApJl1EFUsqzxHD1yy_